# mapkitでの円の半径をアニメーションさせたい

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

地図上に表示した円を削除せずに、半径を変える方法を教えてください。

円の半径を変えるときに、以下のサイトを参考にして、このようなプログラムを書きました。実際のプログラムは、ドラックに合わせて、指が動くたびに何度も更新されます。
このプログラムだと、作ったサークルを一度削除してから、新たに大きめのサークルを生成し、addOverlayをしているので、これを何度も細かに繰り返したとき、綺麗にアニメーションされません。円が消えて、表示される、消えて、表示される、というのが少しですが、見えてしまいます。

なので、削除せずに円の半径を変える方法を知りたいです。

`myCircle.radius = 1200`と書こうと思ったのですが、

> Cannot assign to property: 'radius' is a get-only property

と言われてしまいます。よろしくお願いします。

[地図上に図形を描く(円)- swift docs](https://sites.google.com/a/gclue.jp/swift-docs/ni-yinki100-ios/7-mapkit/de-tu-shangni-tu-xingwo-miaoku-yuan)

```
    // 円を描画する(半径1000m).
    let myCircle: MKCircle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: center, radius: CLLocationDistance(1000))

    // mapViewにcircleを追加.
    myMapView.addOverlay(myCircle)
    mapView.removeOverlay(myCircle)

    // 再び円を描画する(半径1200m).
    let myCircle: MKCircle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: center, radius: CLLocationDistance(1200))

    // mapViewにcircleを追加.
    myMapView.addOverlay(myCircle)
```

Comment: see [Smooth resizing of MKCircle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571332/smooth-resizing-of-mkcircle) やりたいのはこういうことでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。そうです。そういうことがしたかったです！あまり解読できなかったのですが、CGRectでcircleというイメージをmapViewの中に書くということでしょうか?

Comment: `MKCircleView`のカスタムサブクラスを作成して、CABasicAnimationで動かしています。これは仕組みとしては単純なのですけど、ややMapKitとCore Animationの知識が必要な感じです。公式リファレンスで両者の知識を身に付ければ、きっと読み解けると思います。